# JavaFx Dialogs cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, dialog

I am kind of confused as i am using Eclipse Luna in my kind of big project, and i was using JavaFX fine, for now.
I am trying to implement a Process Dialog as shown in [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/#progress-dialog)
And here is a tricky part, my eclipse does not recognize nor know what to do with those few badly importat lines

```
Dialogs.create()
    .owner(stage)
    .title("Progress Dialog")
    .masthead("Searching for friends")
    .showWorkerProgress(service);
```

The first word in this code gets underlined and a mysterious

> Dialogs cannot be resolved

show up as i hover above it..
I can not understand this matter as i use a lot of JavaFX in this project, and i did not have any issues with any part. Alerts, windows and all stuff like that works fine, only this thing is kind of strange for me.
Also, i do use `JavaFX ver 8.0.45-b11`, and it disturbs me as somewhere i found that

> JavaFX has never had a dialogs API, which has always seemed to be a
>   glaring omission – but no more! It has (finally!!!) been decided that
>   JavaFX 8u40 will be the first release that will include a dialogs API.

Could someone please tell me if there is any mysterious thing that one must do to use this JavaFX Dialogs API?

Comment: The link you have is using the ControlsFX dialogs API, which is a third part API that is not part of the standard JavaFX API. The standard JavaFX dialogs API introduced in 1.8.0_40 is based on ControlsFX but is not identical to it; in particular there is no `Dialogs` utility class. Instead, there is a [`Dialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) class and an [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) class: check the Javadocs and work from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use 3rd party dialogs going forward. Learn how to use the dialogs native to jdk8u40+ from this [JavaFX Dialogs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) page.

Comment: When writing dialogs logic, write it the **lambda** way using the example shown in this [Dialogs JavaFX 9 page](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html). It shows how to transform the traditional dialog build logic to something like this: dialog.showAndWait().filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK).ifPresent(response -> formatSystem());